# python make virtualenv with specific python version fails

Tags: python, ruby, virtualenv

I am used to ruby where you specify the ruby gemset and the ruby version using

```
.ruby-version
.ruby-gemset
```

in python, it seems, that you have to use this syntax:

```
mkvirtualenv --python /usr/local/opt/pyenv/versions/3.4.2 test1
```

but it fails with this output:

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/opt/pyenv/versions/3.4.2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 784, in main
    popen = subprocess.Popen([interpreter, file] + sys.argv[1:], env=env)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

when running without specifying the python version it works like so:

```
mkvirtualenv test2                                                              ✱
New python executable in test2/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in test2/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
```

Comment: Does it work when you *don't* specify a particular Python version?

Comment: hi @jonrsharpe, yes. added it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the actual python executable name... e.g. `virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python2.7 py2.7` or `virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3 py3`, not the directory. Both should work on OS X with the Homebrew-installed versions of Python, fwiw...